# Из-за чего выдает ошибку в коде?

Tags: java, классы

```
    class Car
    {
        public final static String color = "Красный" ;
        public final static String bodyType = "Купе" ;
        public static String accelerate()
        {
            String motion = "Ускоряется..." ;
            return motion ;
        }

    }


    class FirstObject
    {

         public static void main ( String[] args)
         {

              System.out.println( "Цвет: " + Car.color ) ;
              System.out.println( "Тип кузова: " + Car.bodyType ) ; 
              System.out.println( Car.accelerate() ) ;
              Car Porsche = new Car() ; 
              System.out.println( "Цвет Porsche " + Porsche.color ) ;
              System.out.println( "Тип кузова Porsche " + Porsche.bodyType );
              System.out.println( Porsche.accelerate() ) ;

        }


  
    }
    // Выдает ошибку: The static method accelerate() from the type Car should be 
    //accessed in a static wayJava(603979893)
    // Но файл работает
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Статический метод можно вызывать только от класса `Car.accelerate()` а не  у экземпляра. Решайте, либо вам нужен статический метод и обращаться надо `Car.accelerate()`, либо не нужен (потому что хотите чтобы у каждого экземпляра был свой метод) и тогда убрать слово `static`